# C Macro for type safe callbacks

Tags: c, macros

I'm trying to create a very simple event system in c. My interface looks like this:

```
typedef struct EventEmitter EventEmitter;

EventEmitter* emitter_create();
void emitter_subscribe(EventEmitter* emitter, void (*cb)(void*));
void emitter_publish(EventEmitter* emitter, void *payload);
```

Everything works correctly, but in order to register an event listener, I need to provide a function pointer that takes a void *.

```
static void registerOnKeyDown(void (*cb)(void*)) {
  emitter_subscribe(keyDownEmitter, cb);
}

static void registerOnKeyUp(void (*cb)(void*)) {
  emitter_subscribe(keyUpEmitter, cb);
}
```

Is there any way, using a macro or otherwise, to allow users of EventEmitters to provide a typed callback?  Something like:

```
void onKey(int keyCode) {
  printf("%d", keyCode);
}
```

instead of:

```
void onKey(void *keyCode) {
  int code = (int)keyCode;
  printf("%d", code);
}
```

Comment: How are you imagining macros helping here? As far as I can see, you only have one subscribe function, so ultimately everything has to adhere to its interface.

Comment: I honestly have no idea.  I'm new to c.  I wasn't sure if there is some way to make the subscribe function a macro that takes the type into account.  Even if I were to do that, I'm not sure how to know the type when it comes time to publish the event.

Comment: What keeps you from using the second prototype for your callback functions?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `void onKey(void *keyCode) ` you do not have to use `void onKey(int keyCode)`

Comment: @sg7 I realize that I don't have to.  I just don't want the caller to have to do manual casting in order to use the event data.  Is it possible?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with casting to the desire type. The idea of `void *` pointer is to be able to pass various types. If you only pass `int`  in your callbacks you can change `void (*cb)(void*)` to `void (*cb)(int)`

Comment: Then I would end up with something like this:

void emitter_subscribe(EventEmitter* emitter, void (*cb)(int));

void emitter_subscribe(EventEmitter* emitter, void (*cb)(float));

void emitter_subscribe(EventEmitter* emitter, void (*cb)(double));

void emitter_subscribe(EventEmitter* emitter, void (*cb)(my_struct*));

etc...

Comment: The idea is that I want various other parts of my code to be able to create their own event emitters for various events and expose functions that use them as part of their interface.  The user of that interface would have to look at the implementation in order to know what argument types they need to supply for their callbacks, which is not ideal.

Comment: So you know for the future, to get `inline code`, use backticks (`)

Comment: Oh ok thanks.  I've been wondering how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/362347/which-is-better-one-central-detailed-comment-or-several-smaller-ones/362460#362460) on [Software Engineering SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com).

Given your API:

```
typedef struct EventEmitter EventEmitter;

EventEmitter* emitter_create();
void emitter_subscribe(EventEmitter* emitter, void (*cb)(void*));
void emitter_publish(EventEmitter* emitter, void *payload);
```

if you modify it to define the subscription macro on that API instead of putting off on the client code, like this:

```
typedef struct EventEmitter EventEmitter;

EventEmitter* emitter_create();
void emitter_subscribe_impl(EventEmitter* emitter, void (*cb)(void*));
#define emitter_subscribe(emitter, xFunc) emitter_subscribe_impl((emitter), (void(*)(void*))(xFunc))

void emitter_publish_impl(EventEmitter* emitter, void *payload);
#define emitter_publish(emitter, xFunc) emitter_publish_impl((emitter), (void(*)(void*)(xFunc))
```

Then subscribers can call it with the type that they have in hand. As with all API macros, make sure you document the expected arguements completely, so consumers know what to provide and what to expect.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this by simply casting to and from void (*cb)(void *) as needed in wrapper functions:

```
typedef void (*keyCallback)(int);
typedef void (*emitterCallback)(void*);

static void registerOnKeyDown(keyCallback cb) {
  emitter_subscribe(keyDownEmitter, (emitterCallback)cb);
}
```

Comment: Casts are bludgeons; you should avoid using them whenever possible.  Macros, too, are frequently bludgeons — avoid using them whenever possible too.  Those are not blanket prohibitions; both casts and macros have legitimate uses.  But you should aim to minimize the use of both, especially casts, in your code.  Note that you've not defined a prototype for `emitter_create()` in the code in the question.  You've declared the function, but it could take any number of arguments of any type (except that it isn't a variadic function like `printf()`).  Avoid non-prototype function declarations.

Comment: What do you mean that I haven't declared a prototype for it?  Isn't EventEmitter* emitter_create() the prototype for it?  Maybe I don't understand prototypes in c.

Comment: Maybe you don't...that is a declaration for a function that returns an `EventEmitter *` but it says nothing about the number of arguments, or their types.  C is not C++.  To say "this function takes no arguments" in C, you'd have to write `EventEmitter *emitter_create(void);` — now you have a prototype. Define it with `void` too, for symmetry. (In C++, what you wrote is a prototype for a function that takes no arguments. There are strong historical reasons for the divergence. It was crucial to the acceptance of the C standard that the parameterless declaration was open-ended, not a prototype.)

Comment: Ohhh... Yeah I had no idea.  Thanks for the tip.  Im still not sure how I would make a generic emitter without macros or casting though.

Comment: There are no macros in the code you show, so you know you don't need macros. In my book, you should write the callbacks in terms of the callback type. If that's `void (*cb)(void *data)`, then that's what the function is defined as. And yes, it means you do things like `int value = *(int *)data;` (or `int value = (int)data;` — it depends on how the data is passed at the site where the callback is made) to get at the value from the data passed to the callback.  Note that those are necessary casts. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ If you also need to use the callback directly, use two functions, one for regular use, one for the callback.  The callback function unpacks the arguments and calls the other function, so the body of the function is written just once, and the callback is just an 'adaptor', it adapts the callback conventions to the other function's conventions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ok well other than my prototype issue, that's essentially what im doing.  Right?

Comment: Yes — you're on more or less the right track.  You should be writing your `onKey()` function in the style you'd prefer to avoid, though, and not then needing to cast the function pointer in the call to `emitter_subscribe()` in the code in your answer.  You might (or might not) need the `keyCallback` typedef; your callback function should match the `emitterCallback` typedef, so the cast should be unnecessary — but the argument to the `registerOnKeyDown()` function would be an `emitterCallback` and not a `keyCallback`.

Comment: Oh ok.  That seems like it just makes it messier for the person registering their call back.

Comment: That's another way of looking at it, but the casts are a form of fibbing to the compiler. If you call a function that matches `keyCallback` using an expression that matches `emitterCallback`, you get 'undefined behaviour'. Be aware that modern compilers aggressively exploit undefined behaviour to make outrageous-seeming changes to your code, because they know that undefined behaviour can never be invoked deliberately. If you cast the `emitterCallback` pointer to a `keyCallback` before calling it correctly for a `keyCallback`, you'll be OK. The chances are you don't, so you won't always be OK.

Comment: See: [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behaviour #1/3](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) and the following two parts ([#2](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html) and [#3](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_21.html)) to see what I mean — and be scared, very scared!  (OTOH, you may find that a bit much for you as yet; bookmark it for reading later.  But do try to read it now — but go back later if/when necessary.)

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense.  Thanks.  I'll check out that link.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what your types are, you can use C11 generic selection to find out the type of the argument, and provide it as an enum value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct EventEmitter EventEmitter;
typedef void (*INT_CALLBACK)(int);
typedef void (*VOIDP_CALLBACK)(void *);

enum cbtype {
    _INT_CB,
    _VOIDP_CB
};

void _safe_emitter_subscribe(EventEmitter *emitter,
                             void (*callback)(),
                             enum cbtype type)
{
    printf("Registering a callback of type %d\n", type);
}

#define safe_emitter_subscribe(emitter, callback) \
    _safe_emitter_subscribe(                      \
        emitter,                                  \
        (void (*)())callback,                     \
        _Generic(callback,                        \
             INT_CALLBACK: _INT_CB,               \
             VOIDP_CALLBACK: _VOIDP_CB))

void func1(int a) {
}

void func2(void *a) {
}

int main(void) {
    safe_emitter_subscribe(NULL, func1);
    safe_emitter_subscribe(NULL, func2);
}
```

Then from the enum value you will know how you'd need to cast the function again: If it is `_INT_CB` it must be recast as `INT_CALLBACK` before calling; `_VOIDP_CB` as `VOIDP_CALLBACK` and so on.

Comment: This looks like it might be what im looking for.  Can this be used with any arbitrary type?  I want different sub systems of my application to be able to instantiate emitters that can emit out custom events defined by the system itself.

Comment: The complication is that the possible types need to be known inside the generic selection function :D

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured.  I guess I'll stick with casting for now.  I will read up on this though.  I haven't played around with C11 features yet.

Comment: @instantaphex notice that this does casting too, and you need to recast it in the caller, but you can do fancier stuff with it.